# Kusto Timeseries fill up missing values for timechart

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I want to render a timechart which counts the SoftwareVersion based on 1 day steps. I have to fill up forward missing values per day and serial.

The data to start with is:

```
let swVersions = datatable(Date: datetime, SoftwareVersion: string, Serial: string) [
datetime(2022-01-24T13:18:20.8450657Z), '1.29.0', '310160039',
datetime(2022-01-26T06:01:41.8742421Z), '1.30.0', '310160039',
datetime(2022-01-26T12:12:23.2342343Z), '1.31.0', '310160039',
datetime(2022-01-28T12:10:14.3620707Z), '1.17.0', '310160039',
datetime(2022-01-24T05:48:58.9000481Z), '1.29.0', '310160040',
datetime(2022-01-24T10:22:23.4457354Z), '1.30.0', '310160040',
datetime(2022-01-24T15:52:16.2342152Z), '1.29.0', '310160040',
datetime(2022-01-25T05:48:58.9012738Z), '1.30.0', '310160040'];
```

So i need the data like this for rendering the timechart (expected):

```
let swVersions = datatable(Date: datetime, SoftwareVersion: string, Serial: string) [
datetime(2022-01-24T00:00:00.0000000Z), '1.29.0', '310160039',
datetime(2022-01-25T00:00:00.0000000Z), '1.29.0', '310160039',
datetime(2022-01-26T00:00:00.0000000Z), '1.31.0', '310160039',
datetime(2022-01-27T00:00:00.0000000Z), '1.31.0', '310160039',
datetime(2022-01-28T00:00:00.0000000Z), '1.17.0', '310160039',
datetime(2022-01-24T00:00:00.0000000Z), '1.29.0', '310160040',
datetime(2022-01-25T00:00:00.0000000Z), '1.30.0', '310160040',
datetime(2022-01-26T00:00:00.0000000Z), '1.30.0', '310160040',
datetime(2022-01-27T00:00:00.0000000Z), '1.30.0', '310160040',
datetime(2022-01-28T00:00:00.0000000Z), '1.30.0', '310160040'];
```

And summarize and rendering timechart like this:

```
let swVersions = datatable(Date: datetime, SoftwareVersion: string, Serial: string) [
datetime(2022-01-24T00:00:00.0000000Z), '1.29.0', '310160039',
datetime(2022-01-25T00:00:00.0000000Z), '1.29.0', '310160039',
datetime(2022-01-26T00:00:00.0000000Z), '1.31.0', '310160039',
datetime(2022-01-27T00:00:00.0000000Z), '1.31.0', '310160039',
datetime(2022-01-28T00:00:00.0000000Z), '1.17.0', '310160039',
datetime(2022-01-24T00:00:00.0000000Z), '1.29.0', '310160040',
datetime(2022-01-25T00:00:00.0000000Z), '1.30.0', '310160040',
datetime(2022-01-26T00:00:00.0000000Z), '1.30.0', '310160040',
datetime(2022-01-27T00:00:00.0000000Z), '1.30.0', '310160040',
datetime(2022-01-28T00:00:00.0000000Z), '1.30.0', '310160040'];
swVersions
| summarize count() by Date, SoftwareVersion
| render timechart
```

How can I do this?
I am very appreciated for your help.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz I've updated the question how i will summarize and render the barchart. If there is more than one version per day per serial, keep it and count it also. Version drop is also allowed (downgrading of Software Version).

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz Yes I want a daily count of serials per version. But how can i fill up the missing data for this query?

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz Yes a serial will might have more than one record and maybe more than one version in a single day. In this case i want to count all the versions

Comment: Alessio, I have 2 possible solutions, but it's becoming exhausting to try and guess your intentions.  Please put some effort and supply a comprehensive data sample that represents your scenario accurately, including edge-cases.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz I've updated the data above. So more than one version per single day means take the latest by Date. Sorry for the circumstances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[render timechart with (accumulate=true)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/renderoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer)

```
let swVersions = datatable(Date: datetime, SoftwareVersion: string, Serial: string) 
[
    datetime(2022-01-24T13:18:20.8450657Z), '1.29.0', '310160039',
    datetime(2022-01-26T06:01:41.8742421Z), '1.30.0', '310160039',
    datetime(2022-01-26T12:12:23.2342343Z), '1.31.0', '310160039',
    datetime(2022-01-28T12:10:14.3620707Z), '1.17.0', '310160039',
    datetime(2022-01-24T05:48:58.9000481Z), '1.29.0', '310160040',
    datetime(2022-01-24T10:22:23.4457354Z), '1.30.0', '310160040',
    datetime(2022-01-24T15:52:16.2342152Z), '1.29.0', '310160040',
    datetime(2022-01-25T05:48:58.9012738Z), '1.30.0', '310160040'
];
let swVersions_daily_version = swVersions | summarize arg_max(Date, *) by Serial, Date = startofday(Date);
let swVersions_adds = swVersions_daily_version | extend delta = 1;
let swVersions_drops =
swVersions_daily_version
|   extend delta = -1
|   partition hint.strategy=native by Serial
    (
            order by Date asc
        |   extend Date = next(Date)
        |   where isnotnull(Date)
    )
;
let Date_start  = toscalar(swVersions | summarize startofday(min(Date)));
let Date_end    = toscalar(swVersions | summarize max(Date));
union swVersions_adds, swVersions_drops
| make-series sum(delta) on Date from Date_start to Date_end step 1d by SoftwareVersion
| render timechart with (accumulate=true)
```

[image: Timechart]

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA5WU246bMBCG75F4B98FKoJsYw6hyl3foFEvWlWRF5zEKofINptNlYfvGIJCssk2ayyBzcw3M78HKmGQPvwQSsu20WiJSm7geqmE940bkdu1MLIWAfrebsyBK3E2zpE2SjZbeCGU5NW49pHr/HIdBGP09SimdI7JnLIViXKS5RSHGYtxEqc//QDNSEgXIZ7BU0QwSTCOFrPgESNZ4STHJGckzFJGGSVnRoQ/wSA0h0mjkEYMZjQyyNOMrGfgnLAwSihO8VgLSZ9msBWOc5blcRYuMMYsI/f1YPgjBiRB%201oYi9MoZvf1%20A8jzmMoJ%20n1IDH9fB7xtBZC0yh7mIfr/P7qOtVV761LLqvj%20nVYQidO2vKEdFfXXMm/AnG1Xdf8rW/PAH3x0cvx3IEBsnvW03Bl2k3Jj72V/z4WL0t9FeIm%20gmJNyOaEpWiMhwsyZ18VbsHiOs8orjOCYS6Ac3JsL2HFKWxsXayMSF8O5Dp9rhsuJGv4lLUoLY33MbRqlIoa9MXzHVxeT0JeVajgeWgw7XVYSeUQFI3rWm6qpqawO1cr91c93oiQJlWF7ziyntwNhPha9kMRN%20fomxe6BnUeMS9e9dYoW7OL3h3GFbZmv8Rcw3SCW1pXq%207j8C9l2Oj2npalGkveWkj9oiUvfbX/zoLVmACotueL3bW9SDNDnm8KLq6q4CxNKoT/j8X6oxrUQUAAA==https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA5WU246bMBCG75F4B98FKoJsYw6hyl3foFEvWlWRF5zEKofINptNlYfvGIJCssk2ayyBzcw3M78HKmGQPvwQSsu20WiJSm7geqmE940bkdu1MLIWAfrebsyBK3E2zpE2SjZbeCGU5NW49pHr/HIdBGP09SimdI7JnLIViXKS5RSHGYtxEqc//QDNSEgXIZ7BU0QwSTCOFrPgESNZ4STHJGckzFJGGSVnRoQ/wSA0h0mjkEYMZjQyyNOMrGfgnLAwSihO8VgLSZ9msBWOc5blcRYuMMYsI/f1YPgjBiRB%201oYi9MoZvf1%20A8jzmMoJ%20n1IDH9fB7xtBZC0yh7mIfr/P7qOtVV761LLqvj%20nVYQidO2vKEdFfXXMm/AnG1Xdf8rW/PAH3x0cvx3IEBsnvW03Bl2k3Jj72V/z4WL0t9FeIm%20gmJNyOaEpWiMhwsyZ18VbsHiOs8orjOCYS6Ac3JsL2HFKWxsXayMSF8O5Dp9rhsuJGv4lLUoLY33MbRqlIoa9MXzHVxeT0JeVajgeWgw7XVYSeUQFI3rWm6qpqawO1cr91c93oiQJlWF7ziyntwNhPha9kMRN%20fomxe6BnUeMS9e9dYoW7OL3h3GFbZmv8Rcw3SCW1pXq%207j8C9l2Oj2npalGkveWkj9oiUvfbX/zoLVmACotueL3bW9SDNDnm8KLq6q4CxNKoT/j8X6oxrUQUAAA==)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Sorry for the circumstances.